# Jersey not invoking GSON Handler for String

Tags: java, jersey, gson

I created a simple project to test jersey + GSON, available at https://github.com/i23098/jerseyGsonHandler

I created `GsonMessageBodyHandler implements MessageBodyReader<Object>, MessageBodyWriter<Object>` that does `System.out.println` on `readFrom` and `writeTo` so that I could check if it is being invoked.

```java
    @Override
    public Object readFrom(Class<Object> type, Type genericType, Annotation[] annotations, MediaType mediaType, MultivaluedMap<String, String> httpHeaders, InputStream entityStream) throws IOException, WebApplicationException {
        Type jsonType = Collection.class.isAssignableFrom(type) ? genericType : type;
        Object o;
        try (Reader jsonReader = new InputStreamReader(entityStream, StandardCharsets.UTF_8)) {
            o = gson.fromJson(jsonReader, jsonType);
        }

        System.out.println("GsonMessageBodyHandler.readFrom() -= " + o + " =-");

        return o;
    }

    @Override
    public void writeTo(Object o, Class<?> type, Type genericType, Annotation[] annotations, MediaType mediaType, MultivaluedMap<String, Object> httpHeaders, OutputStream entityStream) throws IOException, WebApplicationException {
        Type jsonType = Collection.class.isAssignableFrom(type) ? genericType : type;
        try (OutputStreamWriter writer = new OutputStreamWriter(entityStream, StandardCharsets.UTF_8)) {
            gson.toJson(o, jsonType, writer);
        }

        System.out.println("GsonMessageBodyHandler.writeTo() -= " + o + " =-  " + gson.toJson(o, jsonType));
    }
```

I have a resource with 2 entry-points, one using string for input/response and another using object for input/response.

```java
@Path("/hello")
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public class HelloResource {

    @Path("/str")
    @POST
    public Response helloStr(String name) {
        System.out.println("Got hello string request [" + name + "]");

        String msg = "Hello " + name + "!";
        return Response.ok().entity(msg).build();
    }

    @Path("/obj")
    @POST
    public Response helloStr(User user) {
        System.out.println("Got hello object request [" + user + "]");

        Message msg = new Message("Hello " + user.name() + "!");
        return Response.ok().entity(msg).build();
    }
}
```

I did a webpage with a simple form (just an input box and 2 buttons) to test the resources with the following javascript:

```js
        function doIt(isSendString) {
            const name = document.getElementById('name').value;

            const opts = {
                method: 'POST',
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
                },
                body: JSON.stringify(isSendString ? name : {name: name})
            }

            fetch('ws/hello/' + (isSendString ? 'str' : 'obj'), opts).then(response => {
                if (response.ok) {
                    response.json().then(rs => {
                        const msg = isSendString ? rs : rs.message;
                        alert('Got: ' + msg);
                    }).catch(e => {
                        console.log(response, e);
                        alert('Error parsing data');
                    });
                } else {
                    console.log(response);
                    alert('Error fetching data');
                }
            });

            return false;
        }
```

Using the `/str` entry point, it doesn't work as intended...

- In the network tab it can be seen that the request is `"Ricardo Almeida"` and the response is `Hello "Ricardo Almeida"!` instead of `"Hello Ricardo Almeida!"` or, at most, `'Hello Ricardo Almeida!'`.
- On the server, it shows the message from the resource but not from the GSON handler. The string includes double-quotes!!!

```
Got hello string request ["Ricardo Almeida"]
```

Using the `/obj` entry point, it works fine.

- In the network tab it can be seen that the request is `{"name":"Ricardo Almeida"}` and the response is `{"message": "Hello Ricardo Almeida!"}`.
- On the server, it shows the 3 messages as expected (read from GSON handler, resource and write from GSON handler).

```
GsonMessageBodyHandler.readFrom() -= User[name=Ricardo Almeida] =-
Got hello object request [User[name=Ricardo Almeida]]
GsonMessageBodyHandler.writeTo() -= Message[message=Hello Ricardo Almeida!] =-  {"message":"Hello Ricardo Almeida!"}
```

How can I make Jersey use GSON Handler for String (and properly process it)?

Comment: Did you use `@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)` on the handler, too?

Comment: @jan.supol no... but had just tried it locally and it's the same result :(

Comment: Check your `isReadable()` implementation. It should return true for User and String. If it is, then you might need to add a `@Priority` to the provider class

Comment: @PaulSamsotha ```isReadable()``` [always return true](https://github.com/i23098/jerseyGsonHandler/blob/7f71aa3664dbd81478e36ca11f421742bd02a02e/src/main/java/com/github/i23098/jerseyGsonHandler/config/GsonMessageBodyHandler.java#L28)

Not sure where you mean to add the annotation, I tried adding ```@Priority(1)``` to ```GsonMessageBodyHandler``` and still got the same result.

Comment: I manage to get it to work on the receiving part of the parameter. By defining the param as Object, it seems Jersey will now parse it instead of putting the exact String with the double-quotes (i.e. ```public Response helloStr(Object name) {```).

For the Response, it seems that even casting to Object doesn't make a change, if entity is a String, jersey responds exactly the content of the String instead of using the toJson.

Comment: Try to set the Accept header to application/json too in the request. And add the @Produces to to the handler as well as Consumes

Comment: @PaulSamsotha it doesn't make a difference, same result :( It seems that Jersey doesn't call the GSON Handler for String, always using the default - https://eclipse-ee4j.github.io/jersey.github.io/documentation/latest3x/message-body-workers.html - for input, it treats it same as text/plain basically.

Can't find a way to tell Jersey to treat String as all other objects (i.e. go through the gson handler) :( Knowing this, I could just use make those calls use text/plain. But that requires special case handling instead of just always using json.